# How to use ocLazyLoad in Angular 1.5.7 with ui.router?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, oclazyload, angular-amd, angular-component-router

I am developing one SPA using **Angular 1.5.7** . In that application routing is done with "**ui.router**". i have a separate folders for each component like Dashboard,Users,Reports and each folder contains its own component and directive, view and service files.

kindly need some guidance on the below questions

1. Is **Angular 1.5.7** is supports **$ocLazyLoad** ?
2. If its Supports kindly share the some useful links to learn with **ui.router**.
3. How can i achieve **lazyloading of Components** with Angular 1.5.7?
4. Is **Angular 1.5.7** having default method for **lazyloading Components**?

Thanks in advance..